# XAMARIN Forms Create Binding DLL

Tags: c#, ios, dll, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

Developing **Xamarin Forms** application.

To make use of some native iOS controls in Xamarin Forms application, tried binding the objective c files(.h and .a files.) using objective sharpie, have created the dll of the native .h and .a files.

After creating the dll in the iOS solution I added the same into reference and created a renderer class to make use of it.

Issue is I am not able to create instance to any of the classes. Build getting successful but, while running the app, it stops and showing the error as below.

"*Could not create an native instance of the type 'StackViewBinding.StackViewDataProvider': the native class hasn't been loaded.
It is possible to ignore this condition by setting ObjCRuntime.Class.ThrowOnInitFailure to false.*"

Please anyone suggest to resolve this issue.

Thanks,
Prabhakaran

Comment: Are you debugging on device or simulator?

Answer (score 0):

This could be happening because the native library (.a) does not contain all the architectures needed to run, for example if you are running in simulator but your library (.a) only contains device bits (armv7, arm64) it will not work on simulator. Same applies when you run in device but the native library only contains simulator bits (i386, X86_64).

You need to create a fat library using `lipo` command and the resulting libraries from your Xcode project. I have a very detailed post on how to do this, you can find it [here](http://alexsoto.me/bindings-bindings-bindings-part1/)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yes ... this is working with the device but not on simulator. And now I am getting issue with HealthKitUI framework as below,

"Your application using HealthKitUI framework and your device doesn't have compatible SDK version 9.3"

But, I am not using any HealthKitUI in my application.